# Getting value from appSettings.json?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

I'm unable to retrieve the value set in appsettings.json, when I run the code below, I get an error `System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'`

What am I doing wrong?

```
public static IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; } 
....
string facebookApiId = Configuration.GetValue<string>("Authentication:Facebook:AppId");
```

**appSettings.json**

```
"Authentication": {
  "Facebook": {
    "IsEnabled": "false",
    "AppId": "somevalue1",
    "AppSecret": "somevalue2"
  },
  "Google": {
    "IsEnabled": "false",
    "ClientId": "somevalue3",
    "ClientSecret": "somevalue4"
  }
```

**Startup.cs**

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();
    Configuration = builder.Build();
}

public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }
```

Comment: Do you ever set `Configuration` with the result of the configuration builder? Post your Startup constructor

Comment: You just don't assign your `Configuration` property, or assigning it later than you are trying to get value.

Comment: @Tseng posted startup.cs

Comment: And where are you accessing it from? Since it's static it could be everywhere. The Configuration should be accessible outside of startup anyways (recommended is private or protected). Static bears the risk of being called before it's initialized. Change it to protected and see if you get any compile errors after that

Comment: Your code samples are contradictory. In first you have `static IConfigurationRoot Configuration `, in second `IConfigurationRoot Configuration` (non-static).

Answer (score 10):

In your code you actually have 2 (two) `Configuration` properties, one in `Startup`, which is good, as it's being populated and stored in *instance* field, and one in unnamed controller, which is `static` and seems to be never instantiated.

According [MSDN article about the configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration), recommended way to provide your options to the controllers is to implement basic option and configuration object logic, something like this:

```
// option mapping classes
public class FacebookOptions
{
    // maybe string here
    public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }
    public string AppId { get; set; }
    public string AppSecret { get; set; }
}

public class GoogleOptions
{
    // maybe string here
    public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }
    public string ClientId { get; set; }
    public string ClientSecret { get; set; }
}

// load configuration
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    // Set up configuration sources.
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
        .AddJsonFile("appSettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);

    Configuration = builder.Build();
}

// map the configuration to object
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Adds services required for using options.
    services.AddOptions();

    // Register the IConfiguration instance which options binds against.
    services.Configure<FacebookOptions>(Configuration.GetSection("Facebook"));
    services.Configure<GoogleOptions>(Configuration.GetSection("Google"));

    // Add framework services.
    services.AddMvc();
}
```

Now you can easily get the options on your controller via dependency injection:

```
public class GoogleController : Controller
{
    private readonly GoogleOptions _googleOptions;

    public GoogleController(IOptions<GoogleOptions> googleOptionsAccessor)
    {
        _googleOptions = googleOptionsAccessor.Value;
    }
}
```

If you need a whole configuration, you can add some generic class containing all the options and use an [object graph mapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration#binding-to-an-object-graph) from the same article:

```
public class Authentication
{
    public FacebookOptions Google { get; set; }
    public GoogleOptions Google { get; set; }
}

// load configuration
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    // Set up configuration sources.
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
        .AddJsonFile("appSettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);

    Configuration = builder.Build();

    var options = new Authentication();
    config.GetSection("Authentication").Bind(options);
}
```

Edit: Make sure that your classes and configuration sections are named equally as this is important, as turned out.

Comment: when you use it inside the homecontroller method, it will return null? "string gClientId = _googleOptions.ClientId" ?? it should return "somevalue3"

Comment: I don't have such issue. Are you sure that JSON file is there and has been populated correctly? Do you get it by `Configuration.GetSection`?

Comment: First I added Google credentials in the appsettings.json file, next I registered the service in configuratureservices via startup.cs. In the controller and added google options as shown above, then I used this in a statement like so string googleClientId = _googleOptions.ClientId, null is returned.

Comment: Did you get section `Google` inside `Startup`? Did it read correctly?

Comment: I fixed it!, Rename "Google" via appsettings.json to GoogleOptions to match the class model and it works.